# How to get from YAML file the parent id by child value using python?

Tags: python, yaml

I have as an example the below YAML file:

```
servers:
  - type: staging
    distribution_url: https://XXXXX
    artifactory_url: https://YYYYY
```

assuming I have the distribution_url value, how can I get the type value (0) using python commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install a parser, such as PyYAML.  There is no YAML parser in Python standard libraries.

```
import yaml

data = yaml.safe_load(your_yaml_string)  # yaml from a string

# OR:

with open(your_yaml_fname) as f:  # yaml from a file
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

Then:

```
>>> for server in data["servers"]:
...     if server["distribution_url"] == "https://XXXXX":
...         print(server["type"])
...
staging
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? I don't see an issue with this answer.

Comment: Yes then I have no idea why.  FWIW you got my +1 there.

Comment: and if I want to get the value for type (0)?